# Prove that for all $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$ with $a \neq b$, there exist disjoint open balls containing $a$ and $b$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that for all $a,b \in \Bbb R$ with $a\neq b$ there exists $\epsilon, \delta \in \Bbb R^+$ such that $\{x \in \Bbb R : |x-a|<\epsilon\} \cap \{x \in \Bbb R : |x-b|<\delta\} = \emptyset$.

Usually I would at least show an attempt of the proof, but for this one I really have no idea how to start it.

Does anybody have any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: $\delta=\epsilon=\frac{|b-a|}{k}$ with $k$ ...

Comment: This is a trivial question and it appears you are lost in the web of symbols. This is quite expected as modern analysis texts have the habit of making trivialities seem deeply complicated. Do you know what a neighborhood of a point is? Can you indicate it on a number line?

Comment: Do you know that given two distinct real numbers $a, b$ there is another real number lying between them? Even easier, does the last sentence seem familiar if "real" is replaced by "rational"? The question here is an immediate consequence of this fact.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Let $d=|a-b|$. Take $\varepsilon =\delta =\dfrac d2$.

**Edit**: For the sake of argument, assume $\{x \in \Bbb R : |x-a|<\varepsilon\} \cap \{x \in \Bbb R : |x-b|<\delta\} \neq \emptyset,$ where $\varepsilon =\delta =\dfrac d2$. Then there exists an element  $x_0\in\Bbb R $ such that $|x_0-a|<\varepsilon$ and $|x_0-b|<\delta$. Now using triangle inequality, we have $$|a-b|\leq|a-x_0|+|x_0-y|\lt\varepsilon+ \delta.$$ That is $$|a-b|\lt \dfrac d2+\dfrac d2=d=|a-b|.$$ In other words, $|a-b|\lt|a-b|$, a contradiction. Hence $\{x \in \Bbb R : |x-a|<\dfrac d2\} \cap \{x \in \Bbb R : |x-b|<\dfrac d2\}= \emptyset.$

---

I'm leaving a picture below  to give a better understanding of what I've done.Replace  $x$ and $y$ in the picture with $a$ and $b$ respectively.  Note that the point in between $a $ and $b $ is $\dfrac {b-a}{2}=\dfrac {|a-b|}{2}$. I think you can complete  other details.

[image]
Picture courtesy : [Mathonline](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/hausdorff-topological-spaces).

Also observe that any $\varepsilon  $(and $\delta$) satisfying  $0\lt\varepsilon\leq \dfrac {|a-b|}{2}$ will do the work.

Comment: Thank you, if we plug in $d/2$ to replace epsilon and delta then rearrange inequalities isolating x then would this suffice?

Comment: I am afraid I still do not know how to proceed.

Comment: @John Please see my edit.

Comment: @ThomasShelby it would be nice if you could add a picture to make it clear what is going on. OP seems to be very lost on this one.